# Using a generator to make sentences from given words

Tags: python, generator

I'm trying to write a code that can create a few sentences and also words that the user requests, but I'm having some issues and couldn't find the answer from the almighty Google. Looking for any advice (Also, I think there is a way to make it shorter).

```
class CallCentre(object):

    """This is a class."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.nouns = ['koer', 'porgand', 'madis', 'kurk', 'tomat']
        self.targets = ['koera', 'porgandit', 'madist', 'kurki', 'tomatit']
        self.verbs = ['sööb', 'lööb', 'jagab', 'tahab', 'ei taha']
        self.adjectives = ['ilus', 'kole', 'pahane', 'magus', 'sinu']
        self.targetadjectives = ['ilusat', 'koledat', 'pahast', 'magusat', 'sinu']
        self.sentence = 'noun verb target'
        self.twosentences = 'sentence sentence'
        self.beautifulsentence = 'adjective noun verb targetadjective target .'

        self.generators = {
            'noun': self.generator(self.nouns),
            'target': self.generator(self.targets),
            'verb': self.generator(self.verbs),
            'adjective': self.generator(self.adjectives),
            'targetadjective': self.generator(self.targetadjectives),
            'sentence': self.generator(self.sentence),
            'twosentences': self.generator(self.twosentences),
            'beautifulsentence': self.generator(self.beautifulsentence)
        }

    def generator(self, array):
        i = -1
        while True:
            i = (i + 1) % 5
            yield array[i]

    def create_sentence(self, syntax):
        for w in syntax.split:
            if w == 'noun':
                next(self.generators['noun'])
            elif w == 'target':
                next(self.generators['target'])
            elif w == 'verb':
                next(self.generators['verb'])
            elif w == 'adjective':
                next(self.generators['adjective'])
            elif w == 'targetadjective':
                next(self.generators['targetadjective'])
            elif w == 'sentence':
                next(self.generators['sentence'])
            elif w == 'twosentences':
                next(self.generators['twosentences'])
            elif w == 'beautifulsentence':
                next(self.generators['beautifulsentence'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    centre = CallCentre()
    print(centre.create_sentence('noun'))
```

This is the error message:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "this file", line 56, in <module>
    print(centre.create_sentence('noun'))
  File "this file", line 36, in create_sentence
    for w in syntax.split:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: As a note, that giant `if`/`elif` block could be replaced by using the variable - `next(self.generators[w])` - or if you need to validate the content, check the value is in a set beforehand. I.e: `if w in {'noun, 'target, 'verb', ...}: next(self.generators[w])`.

Comment: You can replace all those `'noun': self.generator(self.nouns),` with just `'noun': iter(self.nouns),`. Also, it seems like `create_sentence` should return something, but it doesn't. Did you mean `yield next(...)`?

Comment: I'm flagging for closure due to simple typographical mistake. The answer was missing parens `()` on `str.split`. (see answer by @Latty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling `str.split()`, instead you are trying to iterate over the function (not the *result* of calling said function).

```
for w in syntax.split:
    ...
```

Should be:

```
for w in syntax.split():
    ...
```

Comment: Oh, that was a dumb mistake.. Thought it'd be something more difficult. Thanks.